# R: Joining dataframes and keep latest samples without any duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes which I would like to join in a specific way. First of all, this is my base dataframe:

```
df1 <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), time = c(as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 01:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 04:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 05:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 06:30:00")), weight = c(78, 21, 22, 38))

     ID time                weight
  <dbl> <dttm>               <dbl>
1     1 2011-03-27 01:30:00     78
2     1 2011-03-27 04:30:00     21
3     2 2011-03-27 05:30:00     22
4     2 2011-03-27 06:30:00     38
```

Then I have a second dataframe:

```
df2 <- tibble(ID = c(1,  2, 2), time = c(as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 00:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 04:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 06:00:00")), newValue = c(45, 5, 3))

     ID time           newValue
  <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>
1     1 2011-03-27 00:30:00       45
2     2 2011-03-27 04:30:00        5
3     2 2011-03-27 06:00:00        3
```

I now want to do a left join on `ID` and `time`. However, while `==` should be used to join rows for `ID`, I want to join rows considering `time` with `>`. In words, the resulting dataframe should contain the rows of `df1` and the joined elements of `df2` where `df2$Time <=df1$Time`. For that I'm using `fuzzyjoin`:

```
df_all <- fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("ID", "time"), match_fun = c(`==`, `>`))
```

This gives me:

```
   ID.x time.x              weight  ID.y time.y              newValue
  <dbl> <dttm>               <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>
1     1 2011-03-27 01:30:00     78     1 2011-03-27 00:30:00       45
2     1 2011-03-27 04:30:00     21     1 2011-03-27 00:30:00       45
3     2 2011-03-27 05:30:00     22     2 2011-03-27 04:30:00        5
4     2 2011-03-27 06:30:00     38     2 2011-03-27 04:30:00        5
5     2 2011-03-27 06:30:00     38     2 2011-03-27 06:00:00        3
```

So, for `ID == 1` everything is fine. I only have one entry in `df2` for that ID and therefore the same `newValue` is used in both rows. Line 3 is also correct, because there is only one row in `df2` where `ID == 2` and `df2$Time < "2011-03-27 05:30:00"`. However, for `ID == 2` and `df1$Time == 2011-03-27 06:30:00`  both entries in `df2` do fullfill the join requirement, because `2011-03-27 04:30:00` and `2011-03-27 06:00:00` are both smaller than `2011-03-27 06:30:00`.

What I actually want is that in case of multiple matches only the entry in `df2` with the latest timestamp should be used. So in the above case, only line `5` should be kept and there shouldn't be the line `4`. As I have a huge database, joining all rows and then selecting afterwards is no option for me - so is there away to implement this logical on the joining level?

Answer (score 2):

Joining is the process of building the cross product of all possible row pairs between two tables followed by filtering the rows matching the condition (e.g. `df1$ID == df2$ID & df2$time <= df1$time`). There is no other way to do this.

To minimize overhead, you can replace the fuzzy join with a `full_join` followed by a `filter`. These more primitive functions can be directly converted e.g. to SQL (see dbplyr package for details) to be executed in the db management system of your choice. We can not help further with the database due to the lack of naming the specific setup.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), time = c(as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 01:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 04:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 05:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 06:30:00")), weight = c(78, 21, 22, 38))
df2 <- tibble(ID = c(1, 2, 2), time = c(as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 00:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 04:30:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-03-27 06:00:00")), newValue = c(45, 5, 3))


df1 %>%
  full_join(df2 %>% rename(time2 = time), by = "ID") %>%
  filter(time2 <= time) %>%
  group_by(ID, time) %>%
  arrange(desc(time2)) %>%
  slice(1)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 5
#> # Groups:   ID, time [4]
#>      ID time                weight time2               newValue
#>   <dbl> <dttm>               <dbl> <dttm>                 <dbl>
#> 1     1 2011-03-27 01:30:00     78 2011-03-27 00:30:00       45
#> 2     1 2011-03-27 04:30:00     21 2011-03-27 00:30:00       45
#> 3     2 2011-03-27 05:30:00     22 2011-03-27 04:30:00        5
#> 4     2 2011-03-27 06:30:00     38 2011-03-27 06:00:00        3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wedded to `tidy` here is a `data.table` solution that seems to work and will likely be > 10 times faster if you really do have a large dataset (> 1MM rows).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[df2, newValue:=i.newValue, on=.(ID, time > time)]
df1
##    ID                time weight newValue
## 1:  1 2011-03-27 01:30:00     78       45
## 2:  1 2011-03-27 04:30:00     21       45
## 3:  2 2011-03-27 05:30:00     22        5
## 4:  2 2011-03-27 06:30:00     38        3
```